# php oop file upload form with validation process

Tags: php, file-upload, mysqli

Hi I'm new to OOP practices, I'm trying to get a file upload onto working with PHP by using functions. What I require my file upload system to do is:

**File Upload Specification**

1. Specific file extensions - i.e. jpg, jpeg, gif, png etc
2. Upload to a specific directory but upon the upload create a new directory based on the i.d of the entry in the SQL database - i.e. house id 234 would create the upload directory 234.
3. Keep the extension of the file that has been uploaded - i.e if a jpeg has been uploaded keep that extension.
4. Rename the file to something a random filename

I have created function but I keep getting thrown the following error

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/undergradpad/classes/class.House.inc on line 52
```

I don't understand what this means as the File does not exist in that directory however the statement to add the details on the house are inputted to the database.

Any help would be warmly received.

My code is as follows:

classes/class.House.inc

```
<?php
    include("connect/class.Database.inc");

    class House extends Database {
    public function insert ($field) {

         $sql = "INSERT INTO houses(bedrooms, description, roadname, postcode, price, deposit, contractlength, available, bathrooms, livingrooms, outdoorspace, furnishing, contactdetails) 
              VALUES('".$this->bedrooms."', '".$this->description."', '".$this->roadname."', '".$this->postcode."', '".$this->price."', '".$this->deposit."', '".$this->contractlength."', '".$this->available."', '".$this->bathrooms."', '".$this->livingrooms."', '".$this->outdoorspace."', '".$this->furnishing."', '".$this->contactdetails."')";
            $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql) or die("insert:".$mysqli->error());

             $allowedExtensions = array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png"); 
             $path =  "../files/uploads/houses_gallery/$mysqli->insert_id";

            if (!$this->mysqli->query($sql) && is_dir($path))
                  {
                    die('Error: ' . $mysqli->error());
                  }
                            echo "<h3>1 record added</h3>";
                            mkdir($path);
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "$path");      
        }
    }
?>
```

insert.php

```
<?php 
include("classes/class.House.inc");
include("header.php"); 
?>
<?php
$obj = new House();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $fields = array(
        'description'   => array('required' => True),
        'roadname'  => array('required' => True),
        'postcode'  => array('required' => True),
        'price'     => array('required' => True),
        'deposit'   => array('required' => True),
        'contractlength'=> array('required' => True),
        'available' => array('required' => True),
        'bedrooms'  => array('required' => True),
        'bathrooms' => array('required' => True),
        'livingrooms'   => array('required' => True),
        'outdoorspace'  => array('required' => True),
        'furnishing'    => array('required' => True),
        'contactdetails'=> array('required' => True),
    );
    // We will check ALL fields, and store here any missing ones
        $missing = array();

        foreach($fields as $field => $definition)
        {
            if (!empty($_POST[$field]))
            {   
                 $obj->bedrooms = $_POST['bedrooms'];
                 $obj->description = $_POST['description'];
                 $obj->roadname  = $_POST['roadname'];
                 $obj->postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
                 $obj->price  = $_POST['price'];
                 $obj->deposit  = $_POST['deposit'];
                 $obj->contractlength  = $_POST['contractlength'];
                 $obj->available  = $_POST['available'];
                 $obj->bathrooms  = $_POST['bathrooms'];
                 $obj->livingrooms  = $_POST['livingrooms'];
                 $obj->outdoorspace = $_POST['outdoorspace'];
                 $obj->furnishing  = $_POST['furnishing'];
                 $obj->contactdetails  = $_POST['contactdetails'];
                // We store the content in the object
                $obj->$field = $_POST[$field];

            }
            else
            {
                // Field is required? If so, its lack is an error
                if (True === $definition['required'])
                    $missing[] = $field;
                    }
                        }
                            if (!empty($missing))
                            {
                                echo "Sorry, field(s) missing: " . implode(',', $missing);
                            } else {
                                $obj->insert($field);
                            }
                 }
?>



<div id="mainContent">
<br/>
<div id="insertform"> <!-- Insert Form Div -->

<div id="formWrap">
    <h2>Add a New House</h2>
    <h3> </h3>
    <div id="form">
    <form action="insert.php" method="post" name="insert" id="comments_form">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Picture</div>
    <div class="input">  
    <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" class="detail" />         
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context">e.g. Upload pictures to enable students to view your house.</div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->   
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">No. of Bedroms</div>
    <div class="input"> 
            <select name="bedrooms" id="bedrooms" class="detail">
                <?php 
                 $no_rooms = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8+");
                    foreach ($no_rooms as $number) {    
                        echo "<option value='$number'>$number</option>";
                    }
                ?>                </select> 

                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> e.g. John Smith </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Description</div>
    <div class="input">            
            <textarea name="description" name="description" id="description" class="detail"></textarea>
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> e.g. 3 Bedroom house in London close to University bus stops. </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->      
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Road Name</div>
    <div class="input">        
            <input type="input" name="roadname" id="roadname" class="detail"/>
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> e.g. New Road </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->         
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Postcode</div>
    <div class="input">                             
            <input type="input" name="postcode" id="postcode" class="detail" />
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> e.g. PO5 3QJ </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->  
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Price</div>
    <div class="input">                                      
            <input type="input" name="price" class="detail" id="price" />
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> e.g. "300" - price will be calcuated per month plese only enter a numerical figure </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->        
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Depoist</div>
    <div class="input">                               
            <input type="input" name="deposit" id="deposit" class="detail" />
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> e.g. "200" - please only enter a numerical figure </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->                    
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Length of contract</div>
    <div class="input">                     
            <input type="input" name="contractlength" id="contractlength" class="detail" />
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> e.g. 10 months, please only enter a numerical figure. </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->      
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Available</div>
    <div class="input">                                    
            <select name="available" id="available" class="detail">
                <?php 
                 $months = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "Septemeber", "October", "Novemeber", "December");
                    foreach ($months as $month) {   
                        echo "<option value='$month'>$month</option>";
                    }
                ?>          
            </select>                   
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> e.g. September </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row --> 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Bathrooms</div>
    <div class="input">                                                 
            <select name="bathrooms" id="bathrooms" class="detail">
                <?php 
                 $no_bathrooms = array("1", "2", "3+");
                    foreach ($no_bathrooms as $number) {    
                        echo "<option value='$number'>$number</option>";
                    }
                ?>          
            </select>
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->               
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Living Rooms</div>
    <div class="input">                  
            <select name="livingrooms" id="livingrooms" class="detail">
                <?php 
                 $no_livingrooms = array("1", "2+");
                    foreach ($no_livingrooms as $number) {  
                        echo "<option value='$number'>$number</option>";
                    }
                ?>        
            </select>
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context">  </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->                  
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Outdoor Space</div>
    <div class="input">                     
            <select name="outdoorspace" id="outdoorspace" class="detail">
                <?php 
                 $outdoor_space_op = array("Garden", "No Garden");
                    foreach ($outdoor_space_op as $option) {    
                        echo "<option value='$option'>$option</option>";
                    }
                ?>        
            </select>
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context">  </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->                  
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Description</div>
    <div class="input">                    
            <select name="furnishing" id="furnishing" class="detail">
                <?php 
                 $furnishing_type = array("Fully Furnished", "Part Furnished", "Not Furnished");
                    foreach ($furnishing_type as $option) { 
                        echo "<option value='$option'>$option</option>";
                    }
                ?>        
            </select>
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context">  </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->                      
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Contact No</div>
    <div class="input">                   
            <input type="input" name="contactdetails" id="contactdetails" class="detail"  />
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> e.g. 01682 853214</div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->         
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Email Address</div>
    <div class="input">                   
            <input type="input" name="email" id="email" class="detail"  />
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> e.g. john.smith@gmail.com</div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->                         
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Message" />
                    <div class="submit"> </div> <!-- end submit -->                
        </form>
</div> <!-- end form -->
</div> <!-- end form wrapper -->

 </div>
<?php include("footer.php");?>
```

Comment: Nice [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: As a general advise, try to install a debugger (like [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) or Zend Debugger), so that you can see the step-by-step execution of your code. A more primitive approach would be to `var_dump` the `$path` contents before the `mkdir`. Also, is there a reason for `"$path"` instead of `$path`? Could you show the contents of `$_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name']`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$path =  "../files/uploads/houses_gallery/$mysqli->insert_id";
```

Should probably be

```
$path =  "../files/uploads/houses_gallery/" . $this->mysqli->insert_id;
```

And as Mark B pointed out, beware of sql injections. You should prepare your queries: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

You are also using mysqli inconsistently.  I'm not sure whether it should be `$mysqli` or `$this->mysqli`, but I would certainly guess the latter.

Is this condition doing what you intend it to?  Checking whether the query fails AND the directory already exists?

```
        if (!$this->mysqli->query($sql) && is_dir($path))
              {
                die('Error: ' . $mysqli->error());
              }
```

That excerpt is also the second time you have called `mysqli->query` for the same insert.  I think you should be using `$result` here instead, rather than trying to insert it twice.

And really, I don't think you need to check whether the query has failed at this point anyway, since you have already checked whether it failed with:

```
$result = $this->mysqli->query($sql) or die("insert:".$mysqli->error());
```

Which effectively prevents that condition from ever evaluating to true, if written as:

```
if (!$result && is_dir($path))
```

Comment: I see that this makes it more simplified however I still get the same error as before

Comment: Okay, does the House table have an AUTO_INCREMENT column to return as the insert_id?  If there is not an AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, the insert_id you get back will be 0, as stated on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Comment: Also, have any rows been successfully inserted when you run this?  Have any directories or files been created by it?  And, as  Andrés has already stated, a var_dump of the $path before the failure might be helpful, particularly if it turns out to be '../files/uploads/houses_gallery/0', as it should be if my previous comment is correct, for instance.

Comment: yes the column is auto incrementing and the form contents are inputted into the sql table but the folder is not been created and the var dump simply outputs `bool(false)`

Comment: Is that a var_dump of `mkdir($path)`?  That isn't useful.  We know that fails.  We need a var_dump of $path.  Just add a line `var_dump($path);` just before the mkdir statement.  My knowledge of PHP is not infinite, but I can't imagine why $path would be bool(false).

Comment: oh i see my bad i get this message `string(32) "../files/uploads/houses_gallery/"` any ideas on what this means?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19518/discussion-between-femtorgon-and-gurtarandeep)